# Should I be using interfaces like this?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, interface

I find myself in a situation where I want to use interfaces, but am second guessing myself.

I'm writing an application to handle insurance applications. There is an Application object that holds all the data about the insurance application. This includes data about the person insured, the entity that will own the insurance policy, and the entity that will pay for the insurance coverage.

I use the term entity because the policy can be owned (or paid for) by a Person or a Trust. I know when I'm dealing with an Owner or a Payor, but I don't necessarily know if that Owner or Payor is a Person or a Trust. I initially created the Owner interface to cut down on casting and instanceof-based logic. I planned to staple on the Payor interface, but am now second-guessing myself.

That's probably all you need to know for now. Here's some code:

```
public class Application{
    private Person insured;
    private Owner owner;
    private Payor payor;

    ...

}

public interface Owner{
    public void setAddress(Address address);
    public Address getAddress();

    public void setId(String id);
    public String getId();

    public void setPIN(String pin);
    public String getPIN();
}

public interface Payor{
    public void setAccount(Account account);
    public Account getAccount();
}

public class Person implements Owner, Payor{
    ...
}

public class Trust implements Owner, Payor{
    ...
}
```

Am I on the correct path or should I be doing this differently? The thing that's giving me pause is the fact that not every Person will be an Owner or a Payor.

As I think about it more, I feel like Owner and Payor aren't "behaviors" so much as "classifications." Does that make my use of interfaces here incorrect? If so, do you have any recommendations for alternate solutions? Preferably ones that allow me to continue using Persons and Trusts transparently as Owners and Payors?

Part of my concern comes from less-familiar developers confusing a Person for an Owner like below.

```
Application app = new Application();
Person timmy = new Person();
Owner smithFamilyTrust = new Trust();
Payor steve = new Person();

app.setInsured(timmy);
app.setOwner(smithFamilyTrust);
app.setPayor(steve);

...

//this would run, but would be wrong
if(timmy instanceof Owner){
   //Do Owner Stuff.
}

//this would run, and be correct
Owner owner = app.getOwner();
//Do Owner Stuff
```

**Edit to clarify "Owner Stuff"**

At this point, "owner stuff" is simple. Things like getting/setting the owner's id, PIN, or Address:

```
//I want this
app.getOwner().getId();
app.getOwner().getPIN();
app.getOwner().getAddress();

//I don't want this
if(app.getOwner() instanceof Person){
    Person owner = app.getOwner();
    owner.getId();
    owner.getPIN();
    owner.getAddress();
} else if(app.getOwner() instanceof Trust){
    Trust owner = app.getOwner();
    owner.getId();
    owner.getPIN();
    owner.getAddress();
}
```

Initially I thought I should go with some sort of Entity superclass and have Person and Trust extend that class, but they store and retrieve IDs and PINs differently. The different implementation of the same behavior led me to interfaces.

I could still go with an Entity superclass, but I feel like I can't accurately represent a "generic" ID or PIN for that Entity class. I'd have to implement either Person's ID and PIN logic or Trust's ID and PIN logic, then override that in the other class. That feels wrong to me. I suppose Entity could be an abstract class that Person and Trust extend, but I'm not sure that's better than using an interface.

Comment: When would you use `timmy instanceof Owner` and what kind of "owner stuff" would you do?  Seems to me that whether an entity is an owner or a payor is only defined in the context of a specific application, and there you already know which is which.

Comment: A type system is probably a bit weak for defining the sort of semantics you're talking about. Communicating that kind of tacit information is generally done through other means, pick any of pair programming, comprehensive test/spec suite including examples of how to use each class or old fashioned powerpoint sessions.

Comment: @Dmitri "owner stuff" at this point is simple things like getting a mailing address, tax ID, or PIN.  So, what I want to do is app.getOwner().getAddress() without having to determine if the owner is a Person or a Trust.

Answer (score 3):

Using interfaces in this way may or may not be appropriate. If you're second guessing yourself then you've probably introduced them too early.

The practical purpose of interfaces is to allow a piece of code to run against multiple implementations e.g.

```
interface Contactable
  Address getAddress()
end

class Person implements Contactable
  Address getAddress(){
    ...
  }
end

class Company implements Contactable
  Address getAddress() {
    ...
  }
end

class RenewalReminderJob extends CronJob {
  public void perform() {
    for(Contactable upForRenewal : listOfCompaniesAndPeople) {
      remind(upForRenewal)
    }
  }
}
```

Generally it's better to start with concrete classes and then introduce interfaces (using refactoring) when you find that you want to perform operations on different classes that contain the same information. In the example above it would be the Address.

The process of actively searching for interfaces as your code base develops can be really powerful, it allows you to uncover concepts that might not be immediately obvious.

Comment: I love this answer, simply because it subscribes to the notion of building the simplest thing that could possibly work. Getting the idea implemented at a basic level simplifies the job of adding complexity.

Comment: I think this is a great description of when to use interfaces, and it has me wondering if my interfaces are too broad. I could change it from an Owner interface to contactable and identifiable interfaces which follows more with interface naming conventions, but then I don't know what I'd use in Application to store the owner. `Contactable owner` wouldn't work because I wouldn't be able to get an ID or PIN from it without casting.

Comment: Yes, I think you're absolutely right there, smaller interfaces like those can be reused far easier. An interface I use a lot is Labelled which just has a single method getLabel(). I find this extremely useful for the front end because it means I can write code/components that can display any object in my DOM, I just have to implement that one simple method.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way of implementing this is like so 
an application has " 'Role' Entities "  (i.e. entities play different roles on the application)

An Entity can be a person / organisation / Trustee etc

So if you structure your classes this way you wont have a problem .

As an example i can have application with

```
             entity1 (insured )       - person 
             entity2 (payer )         - person 
             entity3 (beneficiary)    - trustee
             entity4 (broker)         - organisation
```

Answer (score 0):

you answered your own question

> Am I on the correct path or should I
>   be doing this differently? The thing
>   that's giving me pause is the fact
>   that not every Person will be an Owner
>   or a Payor.
>
> As I think about it more, I feel like
>   Owner and Payor aren't "behaviors" so
>   much as "classifications." Does that
>   make my use of interfaces here
>   incorrect?

Interfaces are for defining behavior.

Have you tried a subclass approach?

Answer (score 0):

"Owner and Payor aren't behaviors so much as classifications."

Are there behaviours associated with them? For example might you need a method

```
sendInvoice(Payor payor)
```

or

```
Payor getAddressForInvoice()
```

If so then you probably need these to be interfaces, especially if they might be either persons or corporations.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is switch from inheritance to containment. Instead of saying, "a Person or a Trust could be an Owner or a Payor", you would say, "Persons and Trusts can contain Owners or Payors":

```
public class Person {
    public Owner getOwner() { /* will return null if this person is not an Owner */ }
    public Payor getPayor() { /* will return null if this person is not an Payor */ }
}

public class Trust {
    public Owner getOwner() { /* will return null if this trust is not an Owner */ }
    public Payor getPayor() { /* will return null if this trust is not an Payor */ }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the right answer or not, though, because I'm not sure about the business logic behind the "Owner" and "Payor" classifications. If a Person is an Owner, does this mean he can own any Application ? Or, instead, does this simply mean that this particular Person owns this particular Application ? If the latter is true, then you could extend both Person and Trust from a common base interface (f.ex. "LegalEntity"), and use the [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern#Java_example) instead of instanceof checks to provide subclass-specific behavior.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your interfaces. The `Owner` interface just means able to own stuff, and, unless you want to be horribly unfair to poor `Timmy`, I can't see a reason why he should be precluded from owning.

With respect to your concern, I think you're being a bit overprotective: there would be multiple `Owner` instances at any one time in your system and I can't see any potential developer assuming that they can just pick any one and treat that as the owner of a particular application.

Comment: This is the answer I was hoping to see. I think you're right that I'm being a bit overprotective, but I hate leaving something like that open.